# Add custom field to all posts in specific post_type

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, mysql

I want to add custom field 'tnid' to all my posts, and have it's meta value taken from field 'name'

i have the following working query:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)(
SELECT post_id, 'tnid', meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key='name')
```

Now to my question.
I want to add the new custom field only to post_type 'post', not to any other post_type.
How do i have to edit the SQL query to accomplish that?
thx

Comment: And @Philip, you need to do that via MySQL. Why not the WordPress way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this below SQL query will solve your problem-

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta 
            (post_id, 
             meta_key, 
             meta_value) 
(SELECT post_id, 
        'tnid', 
        meta_value 
 FROM   wp_postmeta 
 WHERE  meta_key = 'name' 
        AND post_id IN (SELECT id 
                        FROM   wp_posts 
                        WHERE  post_type LIKE 'post'))
```

Please try it first. I haven't got the chance to try it.

Comment: Adding this way is non-WordPress way by the way.

Comment: He wanted this kinda SQL solution. So I tried to help him like that. I don't think this is a problem., right? @prosti

Comment: we don't know what he needs until reply.

Comment: No man. He questioned in SQL where you proposed or commented why he is not trying the core WordPress methods and functions. So initially he needs SQL based solution. And beside he may have to run this query or code only once. So in that case I think the SQL method is best. So we better not argue on that and there could be a number of solutions. If you propose any WordPress based solution feel free to add it like an answer. Hope I made myself clear. @prosti

Comment: I haven't found his feedback my quest. Maybe he replied and later removed the feedback in that case you are right.

Comment: its working perfectly, exactly what i was looking for, thx the_dramatist